# Need to implement ajax to change value of input field on change in dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm populating row of inputs in my form. Its changes only one row. Since ajax uses id to display the php file output. But I need to change the value on each row...

An early response will be highly appreciated.

```
function getAttendanceSub(categoryName) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getAttendanceSub.php",
        data: "CategoryName=" + categoryName,
        success: function(result) {
            $("#subCategory").html(result);
        }
    });
};
```

## html

```
 $sql_category1 = "SELECT id, unit FROM unitmaster WHERE deleted = 'no' ";
         // echo $sql_batch;
         $res_category1 = mysql_query($sql_category1);
                         while ($row_category1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_category1)){
                        $vall = $row_category1["id"];
                        $captionn = $row_category1["unit"];

                         ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $captionn ?>"><?php echo $captionn ?></option>
    <?php } ?>                                                      
    </select>

    </TD>
    <TD width="10%">
                    <input type="text"  name="txtbox2[]" />
              </TD>
    <TD width="10%"> <INPUT  type="text" name="txtbox3[]"  /> </TD>
    <TD width="10%"> <INPUT  type="text" name="txtbox4[]"  /> </TD>
    <!--<TD stylestyle="width:20px;"="width:50px;"> <INPUT type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]"/></TD>-->
    </TR>
    <?php
    $i++;
    ?>

</TABLE>

<br/>
 <INPUT type="button" value="Add" class="button" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    <!--<INPUT type="button" value="Delete" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />-->


</div>
</div>

<br/>
</div><br/><br/>
 <tr>

        <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/></td>
    </tr>
            </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Will you add your HTML code as well?

Comment: You cannot duplicate IDs in HTML. jQuery/JS can only find the first match. You need to switch to using classes. You also need to show an example of your HTML as well please :)

Comment: how is `getAttendanceSub(categoryName)` called exactly?

Comment: I know you want an *early response*, but without more of your code/HTML this question is difficult to answer. Any answer will be guesswork. Please provide the extra info, or it will likely get closed :)

Comment: I included js code which is used to add rows of input dynamically also the html. Could you resolve it now?